# Export photos from an iPhone 4s using iTunes without iCloud

Tags: itunes, iphone, photos

How can I export photos from an iPhone 4s using iTunes without iCloud? I'm using Windows XP and I don't want to Jailbreak my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't connect my iPhone to my WinXP box, but a bit of Googling returned [this instructional](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2548/iphone_transfer_pictures_from_iphone_to_xp/) which shows how to get the result you are looking for using XP's built-in "Scanner and Camera Wizard".

Comment: so i cannot do that via itunes, right?

Comment: Even on a Mac, photo exports to a computer are not done with iTunes.

Comment: I also use Dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/) on my iPhone and computers (Win and Mac).  The current version will sync photos to your dropbox folder.  If you have that feature enabled *and* you have the dropbox application installed on your Windows machine, it automagically pull down your photos.

Comment: That's a good idea! I didn't know about that feature before. But unfortunately, it is not applicable to my friends in China since Dropbox is not accessible there. Thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: Looks like the photo import capability of XP is the way to go then.